# Converting dynamic flat JSON to hierarchy JSON in Android

Tags: java, android, json

it's me again! upon suggestion from other programmers, i should change my JSON structure to populate a Expandable ListView.
This is the string i get from a HTTP Post:

```
    [{"titulo":"prueba1","nombrelinea":"cortecaballero","monto":"12"},  
     {"titulo":"prueba1","nombrelinea":"cortedama","monto":"15"},
     {"titulo":"prueba1","nombrelinea":"corteniño","monto":"10"},
     {"titulo":"prueba2","nombrelinea":"tintecaballero","monto":"12"},
     {"titulo":"prueba2","nombrelinea":"tintedama","monto":"15"},
     {"titulo":"prueba2","nombrelinea":"tinteniño","monto":"10"},
     {"titulo":"prueba3","nombrelinea":"secadocaballero","monto":"12"},
     {"titulo":"prueba3","nombrelinea":"secadodama","monto":"15"},
     {"titulo":"prueba3","nombrelinea":"secadoniño","monto":"10"}]
```

But i need it to look like this:

```
    [{"titulo":"prueba1","productos":[{"nombrelinea":"cortecaballero","monto":"12"},    
     {"nombrelinea":"cortedama","monto":"15"},
     {"nombrelinea":"corteniño","monto":"10"}]},{"titulo":"prueba2","productos":
    [{"nombrelinea":"tintecaballero","monto":"12"},
     {"nombrelinea":"tintedama","monto":"15"},
     {"nombrelinea":"tinteniño","monto":"10"}]},{"titulo":"prueba3","productos":
    [{"nombrelinea":"secadocaballero","monto":"12"},
     {"nombrelinea":"secadodama","monto":"15"},
     {"nombrelinea":"secadoniño","monto":"10"}]}]
```

Is there a way to rearrange the JSON string that way in JAVA/Android?

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! Eclipse with Android Developer Tools v22.2.1-833290

Comment: Do you want to rearrange the json string on the java object populated by this string ?

Comment: This is what i want:
- Dynamically get the JSON string
- Rearrange it
- Get the rearranged string to send it to the parser.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
public JSONArray convertMyCrappyJSON(JSONArray originalArray){
    JSONArray newArray = new JSONArray();
    for(int i = 0; i < originalArray.length(); i++){
        try{
            JSONObject currentObject = originalArray.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject mappedObj = findObjectInAdded(newArray, currentObject.getString("titulo"));
            if(mappedObj == null){
                JSONArray newSubArray = new JSONArray();

                mappedObj = new JSONObject();
                mappedObj.put("titulo", currentObject.getString("titulo"));

                JSONObject productObj = new JSONObject();
                productObj.put("nombrelinea", currentObject.getString("nombrelinea"));
                productObj.put("monto", currentObject.getString("monto"));

                newSubArray.put(productObj);
                mappedObj.put("productos", newSubArray);
            }
            else{
                JSONObject productObj = new JSONObject();
                productObj.put("nombrelinea", currentObject.getString("nombrelinea"));
                productObj.put("monto", currentObject.getString("monto"));

                mappedObj.getJSONArray("productos").put(productObj);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }
    }
    return newArray;
}

public JSONObject findObjectInAdded(JSONArray updatedArray, String titleToSearchFor) throws JSONException{
    for(int i = 0; i < updatedArray.length(); i++){
        if(updatedArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("titulo").equals(titleToSearchFor)) return updatedArray.getJSONObject(i);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Note, it may need some additional editing, but that should get you on track.

Comment: Thanks! im testing it, now how i print to string the new array?
I've tried with 
        String s = newArray.toString();
 TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.texto);
 text.setText(s);
But it gives me an error from ADT.

Comment: Ell, i've tried to implemet the code on my mainactivity but it seems unreachable for my existing code. Any suggestions on how to include it?

Answer (score 0):

So you are essentially getting A jsonarray of objects and want them grouped by product?

Have you considered parsing the server input into json objects as is, creating another json object where you group them according to the product. And iff json string IS your final requirement you can convert this second json OBJ to string and send it to custom parser if any.